# Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream when create .zip file using ZipFile in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, dropbox-api

I am trying to create a .zip file using the ZipFile library in C#.
The ZIP file contains multiple kinds of music. Music stream downloaded from URL.
Sometimes, **I am Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream when creating a .zip file**.

**Exception:**

```
  System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
  at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
  at Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities.ReadWithRetry(Stream s, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, String FileName)
  at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry._WriteEntryData(Stream s)
  at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Write(Stream s)
  at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
  at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String fileName)
  at Groove.Controllers.Api.GlobalController.DownloadEventMusic(Int32 eventId)
```

> - Error throw from zip.Save(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName)) line.
> - Sometimes if there are only 4-5 music file then **it will work perfectly**. but faced an issue when I have more than 10 files.
> - Is there any problem in WebRequest OR ZipFile() Library?.

```
       using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                eventEntryList.StudioList.ForEach(
                    x => x.EntryList.ToList().Where(y => y.Document.Id != 0).ToList().ForEach(y =>
                    {
                            DBB.GenerateAccessToken();

                            // Getting Temporary Url From Dropbox
                            var lnk = DBB.GetFileTemporaryLink(y.Document.RootPath, y.Document.FileName);

                            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(lnk);
                            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
                            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(y.Document.FileUrl);
                            string fileName = y.EntryNumber != null
                                ? string.Format("{0}-{1}{2}", y.EntryNumber, y.Title, fileExtension)
                                : string.Format("{0}{1}", y.Title, fileExtension);
                            zip.AddEntry(fileName, stream);

                    }));
              
                string tempPath =
                    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",
                        Constants.MediaResourceFolder,
                        ReferenceType.EntryMusic, Constants.EventMusicTempFolder));

                
                if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
                }

                zip.Save(string.Format("{0}/{1}", tempPath, archiveFileName));
            }
```

Here, I am getting Temporary url from dropbox.

**var lnk = DBB.GetFileTemporaryLink(y.Document.RootPath, y.Document.FileName);**

example : (URL : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/AADYfxDZIygbLx66ROJf5aJ9aoRvNc7Z_536SV_CPtM7S9kl-beYKgNCJsILa49ZKjhQtAv9MVRTEPB9ZZUSo_YRLckZ1IarZOiOxerQwxsCTmSdsXZh_iJ-lOjmxTFIzXn35khgOpCJbvgLGj7jJ24riSSE6I0H017cKlINzBZn3xX2Y52K1pe3hQHyJAiG_ELZH9e9FxZM_K47ALqbJ71hc8Oxfx1UVKE55rNTJjz5OzFyUEL-ofQG3Gh6rg9Ztjfk6s-ycn4R0rDcMRqigCHTZ0jV36vW49yozhE_dRhDs0dyLJPOpFfHqOj5kBtGy67WcKUd6bcGq2pk2h2VwIEqLniAhUN7Bp8ljpcdSErTKOGqEPsp-n7Cf-TSZPg8crc)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you get an error when reading from a stream, why do you ask about *ZipFile*? Where does the exception occur? What is the *full* exception, including the call stack? You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: In any case you should *check* the response before using it. If you get a 404 the response stream will be empty. Or you may get a 429 because you issued too many requests and exceeded the rate limit

Comment: Post the exception *in the question*, not the comments. It's unreadable here. In any case you *can't* read anything from a stream if there is no stream to begin with. Check the status code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Question Edited.

Comment: And? Did you check the status code?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , How can I get 404 and 429 code?

Comment: I already posted the link to the StatusCode property. It contains an example that shows how to check it and compare it with known codes like `OK`. Everything else and you need to decide what to do - skip the file? Retry?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am getting 200 status code.

Comment: The code works perfectly for 5-6 files.

Comment: if you want to find what's wrong with your code, *debug it*. Nobody else can do that for you. This has nothing to do with ZipFile, it's about WebRequest. There's nothing wrong with WebRequest. You can make as many concurrent calls as you like. Add proper exception handling to your code. Put a breakpoint inside the `catch` block and check what the `response` properties are when an error occurs. I suspect the status code is *not* 200 in this case.

Comment: BTW you aren't *disposing* the request, response or stream anywhere. All of them need to be declared inside `using()` blocks. In any case, if you lose your connection you *will* get an error. In this case you'll have to retry. You have to check the status code *before* you start downloading though, to avoid retrying bad requests